# The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context. in .Net MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my application in AWS. When I run the application, it seems working but the problem is when I am trying to register or login. It throws error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.
>
> Source Error:
>
> var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, >model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
>   Line 89:             switch (result)
>   Line 90:             {

StackTrace

> [SqlException (0x80131904): The target principal name is incorrect. 
>   Cannot generate SSPI context.]
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1309
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +108
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +937
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +17
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +139
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +448    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +129
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection
>   t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +10
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
>   target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection
>   connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +360
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32()
>   +426    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() +10
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +189
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation) +78
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +175
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +556
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1
>   commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String
>   createDatabaseScript) +90
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection
>   connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection) +171
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection
>   connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection) +76
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +134
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection
>   connection) +119
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +142
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration) +78
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext
>   internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
>   +89    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext
>   objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +116
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState
>   existenceState) +218
>
>   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext
>   context) +151
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
>   +76    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action
>   action) +60
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
>   +357    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext
>   c) +7
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
>   +110    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1
>   action) +198
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
>   +73    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +30    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +16
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   +15    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   +38    System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   +138    System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate) +145
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.d__67.MoveNext()
>   +402    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +102
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +64    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +59    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
>   +309    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +102
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +64    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +24    Aayumitra.Controllers.d__13.MoveNext() in D:\Aayumitra_Doctor\Aayumitra\Controllers\AccountController.cs:88
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +102
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +64
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +97
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__1(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +17
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__11_0()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.b__2()
>   +228    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__3()
>   +35    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__152_1(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Controller controller) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__20_1(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +576    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +132    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

Comment: can you connect to this database from the sql server management studio ?

Comment: @a.tolba, Yes I can connect to db.

Comment: @KeentoLearn how did u resolve this?